# How does the "celle de" construction sound in "n'avoir qu'une envie, celle de ..."?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, démonstratifs

> Je n'avais qu'une envie, **celle de** repartir sur de bonnes bases.

I have always wondered how this "celle de" construction compares to:

> Je n'avais qu'une envie, **c'était de** repartir sur de bonnes bases.
>
> {or}: Je n'avais qu'une envie... repartir sur de bonnes bases.

Does "celle de" sound somewhat more formal? The same goes for:

> J'ai fait une promesse, **celle de** tout faire pour qu'elle ...
>
> {vs}: J'ai fait une promesse, **c'est de** tout faire pour qu'elle ...
>
> {or}: J'ai fait une promesse... tout faire pour qu'elle ...

Answer (score 1):

All three forms are good but first it's

> Je n'avai**s** qu'une envie... (check the Bescherelle)

Then I would say that "celle de" sounds weird when spoken (I am a native French speaker), it isn't incorrect but it makes the sentence a lot heavier. Generally you would say:

> Je n'avais qu'une envie **,** repartir sur de bonnes bases.

Which is shorter but still very formal.

> Je n'avais qu'une envie, c'était **(de)** repartir sur de bonnes bases.

This is still good (the "de" is optional) but heavier too, I would suggest you keep to the short form but it's more of a personal choice.

The same applies to your second example however the "de" is not optional in the second form you suggest cause it's followed by "tout".

As a sidenote only use the "points de suspension" (...) when it's a dialog, they don't look good in text.

Comment: It would be nice in a formal question to use caps properly for French and I.  Celle de reprendrait le mot envie ou promesse, alors que "c'était" introduit la proposition entière. Ce n'est pas du tout pareil....

Comment: Dans son exemple c'est exactement la meme chose puisqu'il n'a **qu'une** envie, "celle de" reprend l'envie et "c'etait" le fait d'avoir l'envie.
En revanche s'il avait dit "j'avais plusieurs envies, dont celle de" ou "j'avais plusieurs envies, c'etait" la il y a une difference.

PS: dsl pour les accents je tape sur QWERTY

Comment: [[On peut utiliser le International Keyboard and taper tous les accents facilement. Il faut l'installer sur son ordi.]], celle d'une envie est anaphorique. c'était introduit une proposition.